# probability of getting three of a kind by drawing 5 cards

Tags: python, probability, playing-cards

so my goal is to try to simulate an actaul deck and draw five cards and check if there is a three of a kind. I have no problem making the deck and drawing five cards, the problem arises when i check for three of a kind

my code:

```
from random import shuffle, sample
from itertools import product
#generating  deck
suits = ["s","d","h","c"]
values = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13"]
deck = list(product(values,suits))
sim = 100000

three_of_a_kind = 0
for i in range(sim):
  shuffle(deck)
  #generating hand
  hand = sample(deck,5)
  #checking for three of a kind
  if any(hand[0][0] == x[0] for x in hand):
    three1 += 1
  elif any(hand[1][0] == x[0] for x in hand):
    three2 += 1
  elif any(hand[2][0] == x[0] for x in hand):
    three3 += 1
  if three1 == 3 or three2 == 3 or three3 == 3:
    three_of_a_kind += 1
prob_three = three_of_a_kind/sim
print(prob_three)
```

edit: my deck only had 12 cards and I changed it to 13 but my question has not changed

Comment: Little bit off-topic: a standard deck has 13 cards, not 12. That may skew your probability value results. The deck is usually represented by "A" (ace),  "2" to "9", then "T" for 10 (ten), "J" , "Q"  (queen), and finally "K" (king).

Comment: thanks will make that change right away

Answer (score 1):

Using collections.Counter to count cards

```
# Counter(...) returns a dictionary of counts of card values
# Checking for count of 3 (card[0] is the card value in hand)
if any(v==3 for k,v in Counter(card[0] for cardin hand).items()):
    three_of_a_kind += 1
```

**Complete Code**

```
from random import shuffle, sample
from itertools import product
from collections import Counter
#generating  deck
suits = ["s","d","h","c"]
values = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13"]
deck = list(product(values,suits))
sim = 100000

three_of_a_kind = 0
for i in range(sim):
    shuffle(deck)
    
    #generating hand
    hand = sample(deck,5)
    
    # Check for 3 of a kind by checking for 3 cards of same value
    if any(v==3 for k,v in Counter(card[0] for card in hand).items()):
           three_of_a_kind += 1
           
prob_three = three_of_a_kind/sim
print(f'{prob_three:.4%}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little trick:

```
#checking for three of a kind
values = sorted(card[0] for card in hand)
if values.count(values[2]) == 3:
    three_of_a_kind += 1 # three, but not four
```

If there are 3 equal values in a sorted list of length 5, it must look like one of these possibilities:

```
C C C x y
x C C C y
x y C C C
```

In each case the middle card value `C = values[2]` is the value we need to count.

---

For more general solutions see: [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
#checking for three of a kind
if 3 in collections.Counter(card[0] for card in hand).values():
    three_of_a_kind += 1
```